# Spring MVC Locale change doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

In my application I have defined the below beans but when I try to change the Locale using the parameter ex: ?lang=es It wont work for me and the thing shows out is the default locale defined in CookieLocaleResolver which is English.

here are my bean classes :

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="resources/i18n/messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="cookieName" value="lang" />
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

what I want to achieve is to change a language using parameter and save that inside the cookie related to that so for further request the locale is the new Locale language !

I also don't want to use the below class because It's deprecated already :

> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping

what is wrong with my declarative bean implementation ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you should define `interceptor` like this:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="resources/i18n/messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
        <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="cookieName" value="lang" />
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>
```

MVC namespace is defined like this:

```
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
....
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd"
```

Make sure you use proper xsd version.

Comment: what is the "mvc" namespace definition in spring ? can you post in here so that I can put it inside my application context deninition ?

Comment: Post edited, just remember to use proper version for your xsd schema

Comment: yeah, let me check your solution !

Comment: Your solution worked like charm ! can you help me for the second question as well ? "is it possible that I have two ways of changing Locale inside my application???"